# Rendering comments in a Backbone view

Tags: javascript, jquery, template, backbone.js, require.js

I want to make show/hide logic more maintainable in my codebase.

Because they are too faraway located in separate js files, it hard for people to maintain.

The  flow in my codebase is:

> require.js init (hide the target DOM at first) → app.js → load_comments.js (show the target DOM if the comments length > 0)

## main.js (require.js manifest file)

```
$("#target_dom").hide();
```

## app.js

```
define([
    'load_comments',
    "jquery"
],function( comments, $){

    return {
        initialize: function(){
            console.log("app.js initialized");
        }
    }
})
```

## load_comments.js

```
var CommentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#comments_section"),
    render: function() {
        var notNullComments = comments.wellFormedComments();
        if (notNullComments.length > 0) {
            $("#target_dom").show();
        }
        var html = commentsTmpl(notNullComments.toJSON());
        $(this.el).append(html);
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From a once over:

- `load_comments` should follow lowerCamelCase -> `loadComments`
- Avoid `console.log`, at least wrap it in something that also takes in to account message severity and filters on that message severity
- Personally I would have used either `comments` or `wellFormedComments` instead of `notNullComments`
- It seems that if there are no comments, that you should get out, and not do the JSON parsing and the html appending
- Where is `commentsTmpl` defined? Smells like a global variable
- It is very confusing to have `#target_dom` there, I am guessing that it is a subelement of `#comments_section`, but I would have called it `#comments` probably?
- Even more confusing is that you append the html to `#comments_section` and not `#target_dom`

All in all, I would go with something like this:

```
var CommentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#comments_section"),
    render: function() {
        var comments= comments.wellFormedComments();
        if (!comments.length) {
            return
        }
        $("#a_descriptive_id").show();
        var html = commentsTmpl(notNullComments.toJSON());
        $(this.el).append(html);
    },
});
```